# Search text for Unicode characters

Tags: unicode

I have to paste Text into a CMS system at work and sometimes I get the Error
"Can't be saved because  (1x, Code U+0001)"

How to I easily find that Unicode character on a Windows machine. I tried pasting the junk of text from Dreamweaver into Notepad and searching for "U+0001", but that didn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: U+0001 is an `01` byte, not even a "Unicode character" per se. Try a hex editor.

Comment: thanks, which one do you recommend that's free? Can I then just search for "U+0001"?

Comment: Search for an `01` byte. And I have no clue about Windows.